# How to catch a yield in a generator without having unused variable?

Tags: javascript, generator, yield

I have a warning `'res' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars` with code similar to this:

```js
function* cancelCredit(action) {
    const res = yield call(/*Nice api call 1*/);
    const res2 =  yield call(/*Nice api call 2*/);
    // Do something with res2
    yield // something
}
```

How can I hide the first `yield` of this generator function without having unused variables, without e.g. `console.log(res)`?

Comment: Just don't assign the result? Why bother, if you don't need it; `yield call(/* args */);` is a valid statement on its own.

Comment: But in that case, the result is one of the returns of the generator :). Everything is in the fact that yield has two meanings here.

Comment: @LaurentLyaudet yield doesn't have 2 meanings. If you remove `const res =`, from the caller of this generator's perspective there will still be 3 yields. Assigning the result of a yield statement does not change this.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. My understanding is that the result of the `yield ...` is whatever value was passed to `next`, so if you don't use that value you can just not assign it to an identifier. Or you can just tell ESLint to ignore the assignment, or use a pattern for unused variables that can be ignored (e.g. `_`).

Comment: Thanks @Evert. I thought that only the third yield in the generator is returned by it. If you can provide the right reference to that in JS specifications, I would accept it as an answer :)

Comment: I'm ok, i don't need the points!

Comment: I did try `_` as a variable name before asking on SO @jonrsharpe. But contrary to Python code, the linter in PyCharm was still complaining about the unused JS variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore any value by using `void` operator on it:

```
void yield call(/*Nice api call 1*/);
```

(this is particulary usefull for eslint rule that forces all the promises to be explicitly either awaited or voided)

However, your case is not one of 2.5 cases where you have to `void` it - you can just ignore the value, it's allowed

```
yield call(/*Nice api call 1*/);
```

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield

> Syntax
>
> ```
> yield
> yield expression
> ```
>
> Parameters
> expression Optional
> The value to yield from the generator function via the iterator protocol. If omitted, undefined is yielded.
>
> Return value
> Returns the optional value passed to the generator's next() method to resume its execution.
>
> > Note: This means next() is asymmetric: it always sends a value to the currently suspended yield, but returns the operand of the next yield. The argument passed to the first next() call cannot be retrieved because there's no currently suspended yield.

Comment: Just in case someone else found this question and has the same mindset than I had and thought that generators were only one way, because that's 90 % of uses. The crucial point here is that a yield expression can return a value given by the caller of the generator between two "yields". In JS, this is done by giving an argument to `next()`. In Python, you would use the `send()` method. The following tutorial on Python is really nice for seeing less basic uses of generators : https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/